# Spark is dropping all executors at the beginning of a job

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm trying to configure a spark job to run with fixed resources on a Dataproc cluster, however after the job was running for 6 minutes I noticed that all but 7 executors had been dropped. 45 minutes later the job has not progressed at all, and I cannot find any errors or logs to explain.

When I check the timeline in the job details it shows all but 7 executors being removed at the 6 minute mark, with the message `Container [really long number] exited from explicit termination request.`.

The command I am running is:

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark --region us-central1 --cluster [mycluster] \
  --class=path.to.class.app --jars="gs://path-to-jar-file" --project=my-project \
  --properties=spark.executor.instances=72,spark.driver.memory=28g,spark.executor.memory=28g
```

My cluster is 1 + 24 n2-highmem16 instances if that helps.

EDIT: I terminated the job, reset, and tried again. The exact same thing happened at the same point in the job (Job 9 Stage 9/12)

Answer (score 0):

Typically that message is expected to be associated with Spark Dynamic Allocation; if you want to always have a fixed number of executors, you can try to add the property:

```
...
  --properties=spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false,spark.executor.instances=72...
```

However, that probably won't address the root problem in your case aside from seeing idle executors continue to stick around; if the dynamic allocation was relinquishing those executors, that would be due to those tasks having completed already but where your remaining executors for whatever reason are not yet done for a long time. This often indicates some kind of data skew where the remaining executors have a lot more work to do than the ones that already completed for whatever reason, unless the remaining executors were simply all equally loaded as part of a smaller phase of the pipeline, maybe in a "reduce" phase.

If you're seeing lagging tasks out of a large number of equivalent tasks, you might consider adding a `repartition()` step to your job to chop it up more fine-grained in the hopes of spreading out those skewed partitions, or otherwise changing the way your group or partition your data through other means.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - this is an app migration from an on-prem cluster to the cloud, so code changes should not have been needed. It turns out I had not allocated enough resources to the job.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. The job was running out of resources. Allocated some more executors to the job and it completed.